# Alert and sound is not working in expo push notification

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, push-notification, expo

I'm developing an application using expo. I want to send and receive push notifications in my application using expo-notifications.
I have integrated the expo-notification and I'm receiving the notification successfully but WITHOUT sound and popup alert. I always have to scroll down the notification panel and then only can see the notification.
This is my code for registering for notification

```
async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
    let token;
    if (Constants.isDevice) {
        const { status: existingStatus } = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
        let finalStatus = existingStatus;
        if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
            const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
            finalStatus = status;
        }
        if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
            alert('Failed to get push token for push notification!');
            return;
        }
        token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data;
        console.log(token);
    } else {
        alert('Must use physical device for Push Notifications');
    }

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('default', {
            name: 'default',
            importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance,
            vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
            lightColor: '#FF231F7C',
        });
    }
    return token;
}
```

And this is my UseEffect where I'm registering and listening for notifications

```
useEffect(() => {
    _gettingRestaurants();

    registerForPushNotificationsAsync().then(token => setExpoPushToken(token));

    // This listener is fired whenever a user taps on or interacts with a notification (works when app is foregrounded, backgrounded, or killed)
    Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener((notification)=>{
        alert(notification);
    });
    Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener((response)=>{
        alert(response);
    });
    
}, [isDataFetched])
```

One more thing, these listeners are also not working. I'm not seeing any alert from these two alerts. Please help me out.

**Thank you!!!**

Comment: Hello @haseeb Ahmed were you able to find a solution to this? None of the answers worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

**For the listeners to work, try:**

Add this in your `app.json`

```
{
  "expo": {
    ...
    "android": {
      ...
      "useNextNotificationsApi": true,
    }
  }
}
```

It didn't work at first for me, but after specifying the permissions, it worked:

```
{
  "expo": {
    ...
    "android": {
      ...
      "useNextNotificationsApi": true,
      "permissions": ["RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"]
    }
  }
}
```

And, if it doesn't work (it didn't for my Main project but did it for another one), you can try to use the legacy notification system that uses `addListener`:

```
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';
import { Notifications as Notifications2 } from 'expo';

Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener((notification) => {
  // New Notifications. Didn't work sometimes
});

Notifications2.addListener((data) => {
  // Legacy notifications. You get a deprecation warning, but works when the new Notifications don't
});
```

Also check if this helps you to get notifications when app is closed on in the background (just after Notification import)

```
Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
  handleNotification: async () => ({
    shouldShowAlert: true,
    shouldPlaySound: true,
    shouldSetBadge: false,
  }),
});
```

**To get notifications with sound:**
If you expect them while the app is in the background, you need to define the `setNotificationHandler` with `shouldPlaySound: true`.
You also need to specify in the notification that you want to play sound like so:

```
const message = {
    to: expoPushToken,
    sound: 'default', // <== the values are 'default' (sound) or null (silent)
    title: 'Original Title',
    body: 'And here is the body!',
    data: { data: 'goes here' },
  };
```

I remember there is also an option to set the priority of the notification. Play with those values until you get what you need.
Search "priority" in this page: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/

Comment: thanks @Juan Vieira a lot this worked for me too

Comment: For me, it was that the **shouldPlaySound** was set to false on the notification handler... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

for me, I face the same problem and no one of the solutions above worked for me.
the problem occurs only when I set the sound as `default` like this

```js
      content: {
        title: "Some title",
        body: "Some body",
        sound: "default",
      }
```

and it was working perfect on ios, but on android the popup notification and sound not showing at all, so I ended up setting the `default` only for ios and `null` for android and I got it to work fine like example below:

```js
      content: {
        title: "Some title",
        body: "Some body",
        sound: Platform.OS === "android" ? null : "default",
      }
```

***Note***: if `null` doesn't work for you, try `undefined` instead

Comment: Not working for me.

Comment: Thanks @Anas. My expo-notifications version wouldn't allow `null` to be used, but does allow `undefined`. It works fine with that and I can see the popup notification using: `sound: Platform.OS === "android" ? undefined : "default"`.

Answer (score 0):

I think Add a this plugins in the **app.json** then my problem solved

```
{
  "expo": {
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-notifications",
        {
          "icon": "./local/assets/notification-icon.png",
          "color": "#ffffff",
          "sounds": []
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}

//And Enable Sound
Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
  handleNotification: async () => ({
    shouldShowAlert: true,
    shouldPlaySound: true,
    shouldSetBadge: false,
  }),
});
```